# Windows 8/10 File Explorer - Minimalist VIEW?

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, windows-explorer

I would like File Explorer to display the title bar and folder contents in a minimalist view.  I've figured out how to hide the menu bar and the status bar but there are still two 'rows' of navigation/organization bars that I haven't been able to figure out how to eliminate.

I don't need the arrow/breadcrumb/search row.
I don't need the organize pull down/view options pull down/get help row.

Can anyone give guidance to make the necessary registry changes to do this?

Back in Windows XP I used the registry modifications packaged in http://toastytech.com/files/throboff.html to make these changes.  Are there any such tools and/or scripts for Windows 8/10?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: @michael frank - Actually I am not - I am looking for guidance to change make similar registry changes in Windows 8/10.  I'll modify my original post.

Comment: @michael frank - I am looking for guidance to make registry changes in Windows 8/10 - as I am not a Windows registry 'guru'.  I am not 'software shopping' as you claim in your comment above.  I'll modify my original post to eliminate any confusion...

Comment: You specifically asked for "tools and/or scripts for Windows 8/10". That is a software request.

Comment: @michaelfrank - Wrong!  'Tools and/or scripts' simply automate manual procedures.  If you happen to happen to have a solution to my request in code snippet form, that would be helpful, especially from a professed Linux guy.  Don't drag this discussion down with petty semantics - your response seems to indicate a lack of understanding of Windows registry modifications.  Sorry to be blunt.

Comment: @michaelfrank - Wrong!  'Tools and/or scripts' simply automate manual procedures.  If you happen to happen to have a solution to my request in code snippet form, that would be helpful, especially from a self-professed Linux guy with little (or no) Windows expertise.  Please don't drag my request for assistance down with petty semantics.  Sorry to be blunt.  If 'tools and/or script' discussions were eliminated from stackexchange you'll find it will lose its usefulness. I have found many,many such solutions helpful to my work...

Comment: look at this tool: http://www.msfn.org/board/topic/170375-oldnewexplorer-118/ it allows Explorer layout tweaks.